# Changing the Expo Icon in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

[This is my app.json file for my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TUFo.png)

I'm trying to change the expo app icon with my own, but having some difficulties. I tried to run expo with expo start -c, but it didn't work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: hello! how are you verifying that the icon is changing? where are you looking?

Comment: @brentvatne  I using a iPhone simulator with xcode.

Comment: it is useful to change the name of the icon file to avoid a cached version getting used when looking inside of the app. change the icon file name and update it in app.json, then reload the app by pressing cmd+r in the simulator, then open up the menu again with cmd+d

Comment: @brentvatne That seems to have work. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to change the icon on the home screen of the iphone? I need to do a demo with it. I need it to look as if it would if a person would download the app from the app store.

Comment: you would need to do a build of the app - `expo build:ios` and distribute it through testflight or `expo build:ios -t simulator` and install in simulator.